# How to create individual data frames through automation, instead of appending onto an existing DataFrame or dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program that forecasts individual stock data. It's very simple and straightforward. The user needs to select one stock and the range of data.

I'm ready to take it up to the next level by allowing this application to create individual forecasts for multiple stocks in one sitting by passing a list of stock symbols to my model. For example, instead of running this program 20 times for 20 different stocks, It would only have to run once for 20 individual stocks. Before, I could only use this application for one at a time.

Let's look at where I currently am. I have already made a dummy list of stocks in `tickers` and started a loop which turned into poorly designed data frames and dictionaries.

```
import yfinance as yf

#stock symbol
tickers = ["LRCX", "FB", "COF"]
# mm-dd-yy formate
start_date = "01-01-2014"
end_date =  "11-23-2019"

stocks = {}

for symbol in tickers:
    stock_info = pdr.get_data_yahoo(tickers, start=start_date,end=end_date)
    stock_info['date'] = stock_info.index
    key_name = 'df_' + symbol 
    stock_info.drop(['Open', 'High', 'Low','Volume'], axis=1) 
    stock_info.rename(columns={'Close': 'y', 'date': 'ds'}, inplace=True)
    stocks[key_name] = stock_info
```

This is the current data frame that the code above produced: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh1F9.png I call it with `stocks[key_name]`. However, this is not the dataframe I had in mind. I want to have a loop that creates individual dataframes for each stock above in my list of `tickers`. Then process the individual dataframes by dropping and renaming each necessary column. In this case, finalizing dataframes with only `y` and `ds` columns for each stock.

[An example of a dataframe I wanted to create for stocks in my list, one df per stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkTE1.png)
Once that is settled, I would  I would like to create loops that pass these dataframes into my model and plots out the data.

The method below did not work for me because I'm using a dictionary and it got overly complicated, I also found out that I need to pass dataframes for `.fit()` when using Prophet() (its a forecasting model developed by Facebook). I would need to loop through each dataframe created and fit them indivudally as such below.

```
for k, v in stocks.items():
    m = Prophet()
    m.fit(stocks)
```

Below is what I have in mind for plotting each dataframe and their respective columns of data. It might help you understand this workflow better. I'm assuming that its very easy to loop over a list for plotting, but I'm also struggling with that. Would i need to automate the size of the subplots as well? Incase I want to try out 30 stocks? Just some of the questions I keep running into.

```
for stock in list_of_df
  # First Subplot
  f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14,5))
  ax1.plot(stock_info["date"], stock_info["Close"])
  ax1.set_xlabel("Date", fontsize=12)
  ax1.set_ylabel("Stock Price")
  ax1.set_title(f"{ticker} Close Price History")
  # Second Subplot
  ax1.plot(stock_info["date"], stock_info["High"], color="green")
  ax1.set_xlabel("Date", fontsize=12)
  ax1.set_ylabel("Stock Price")
  ax1.set_title(f"{ticker} High Price History")

  # Third Subplot
  ax1.plot(stock_info["date"], stock_info["Low"], color="red")
  ax1.set_xlabel("Date", fontsize=12)
  ax1.set_ylabel("Stock Price")
 ax1.set_title(f"{ticker} Low Price History")

  # Fourth Subplot
  ax2.plot(stock_info["date"], stock_info["Volume"], color="orange")
  ax2.set_xlabel("Date", fontsize=12)
  ax2.set_ylabel("Stock Price")
  ax2.set_title(f"{ticker} Volume History")
  plt.show()
```

I would greatly appreciate some guidance here from any dataframe and looping expert. Streamlining this workflow has turned out a lot more difficult than I thought, but essentially I'm trying to make a loop or a function that works for creating any amount of dataframes at once given the proper data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols = [i for i in stock_info.columns]  
cols  = [ i for i in cols if "date" not in i]

for col in cols:

  f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(14,5))
  ax1.plot(stock_info[col], stock_info["Close"])
  ax1.set_xlabel("Date", fontsize=12)
  ax1.set_ylabel(col)
  ax1.set_title(f"{ticker} Close Price History")
  plt.show()
```